# Starting fade animation from a specific point on an UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, optimization, uiview

I’m having trouble with an animation fade-in and fade-out.

I have a simple set up, on the storyboard I have one `UIView` named `myView`.

What I want to do is fade-in `myView` when the user touches the screen, and fade-out `myView` when the user stops touching the screen. I can achieve that with the code below. The fade occurs over five seconds.

The problem however occurs when the user starts touching or stops touching the screen midway through a fade-in or fade-out animation.

For example, when the user stops touching the screen, instead of the fade-in animation gracefully stopping the `myView` fade-in at its current position and reversing with a fade-out animation, what actually occurs is `myView` `alpha` jumps to `1.0` before beginning the fade out.

**Question:**

> What changes to the code below need to be made to ensure that each new
>   animation, fade-in or fade-out, interrupts the current fade animation
>   occurring on `myView` and begins from the current `alpha` of the
>   previous fade animation?

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.myView.alpha = 0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.myView.alpha = 1
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.myView.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Pardon me for ranting, but why on earth would anyone downvote this question? It is beautifully, informatively, and clearly asked. This is exactly how to ask a question on Stack Overflow. It is a _model_ question.

Comment: Thanks, kindly. I try and structure questions I ask as clear as possible.

Comment: Absolutely. Do not be discouraged by downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `touchesEnded` animation interrupts your `touchesBegan` animation, causing the `touchesBegan` animation to be removed and revealing for an instant that you have set the `alpha` to 1.

To prevent this, include in your `options:` the `.beginFromCurrentState` option.

Comment: Wow, it was as straightforward as that. Thank you. I updated the animation options like this and it worked. (Wonder why `BeginFromCurrentState` isn’t the default state.)

`options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState]`

Comment: And the clue was right there in your question! You said, quite rightly: "to ensure that each new animation ... begins from the current alpha of the previous fade animation". You discovered _exactly_ what the problem was. Well done.

Comment: PS The small letter in my `.begin` is because that's the spelling in Swift 3. I'm afraid I think entirely in Swift 3 nowadays.